# How to add sanitize: false option to popover?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to put a button inside the `Popovers` in Bootstrap. But I did not succeed.

I am using Bootstrap-Popover. I want to have a button inside the popover.

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
});
popoverList.forEach(function (popover) {
   popover.getTipElement().getElementsByClassName('.servicePOP').innerHTML += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">My Button</button>';  
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 servicePOP" data-aos="fade-up" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="Title" data-bs-content="A short description">
  <div class="card position-relative">
    <div class="d-block card-icon">
      <img src="images.png" class="card-icon position-absolute start-0 end-0 m-auto rounded-circle mb-5 lazy" alt="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center mt-5 pt-5">
      <a href="# class=" text-decoration-none text-dark ">
                <h5 class="card-title ">Title</h5>
            </a>
            <p>A short description</p>
            <a href="# " class="btn btn-primary ">More Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is:

How to add sanitize: false option to popover?

Comment: Did you try `sanitize: false` or a no-op for `sanitizeFn`?

Comment: @morganney - No. How do I try it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `sanitize: false` as an option which you can pass through when you enable the popover. Inserting HTML in the popover also requires the option `html` to be set to `true` (default false).

[Documentation here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#usage)

```
const servicePOP = document.querySelector('.servicePOP')
const popover = new bootstrap.Popover(servicePOP, {
  sanitize: false,
  html: true,
  content: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">My Button</button>'
})
```

If you have multiple popovers on your page you can initialize all popovers by selecting them by their data-bs-toggle attribute, like so:

```
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, options))
```

Then we can pass our popover config in the options and attach a function to the `content` option. Inside that function we can access the popover trigger element and, in my example, get the attribute `data-pop-example` from it (which I added in the HTML) and insert it into the popover's `content` as the name of the button, like so:

```js
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl,{
  sanitize: false,
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    const popExample = popoverTriggerEl.getAttribute('data-pop-example')
    return `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">${popExample}</button>`;
  }
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:125px"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 servicePOP" data-aos="fade-up" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="Title" data-pop-example="Button 1">
  <div class="card position-relative">
    <div class="d-block card-icon">
      <img src="images.png" class="card-icon position-absolute start-0 end-0 m-auto rounded-circle mb-5 lazy" alt="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center mt-5 pt-5">
      <a href="#" class=" text-decoration-none text-dark ">
                <h5 class="card-title ">Title</h5>
            </a>
            <p>A short description</p>
            <a href="# " class="btn btn-primary ">More Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 servicePOP" data-aos="fade-up" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="Title 2" data-pop-example="Button 2">
  <div class="card position-relative">
    <div class="d-block card-icon">
      <img src="images.png" class="card-icon position-absolute start-0 end-0 m-auto rounded-circle mb-5 lazy" alt="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center mt-5 pt-5">
      <a href="#" class=" text-decoration-none text-dark ">
                <h5 class="card-title ">Title</h5>
            </a>
            <p>A short description</p>
            <a href="# " class="btn btn-primary ">More Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's lot of things you can do inside the function to set the `content`, like accessing JSON data that you want to insert, custom URLs, etc. The sky is the limit here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I have three cards https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmSgp.png. This only works first. Not the second or third

Comment: And How to show description?

Comment: @MahmoudKhoravi See my edit. Just target your popover trigger elements by ID and duplicate code, assuming you need different content for each popover. Code's just fine for 3 cards.  On your second question; I don't know what you mean with description. Lastly, follow up questions are okay generally, but if you want new features than try it yourself first, then ask SO again with your efforts if you get stuck.

Comment: Maybe the manager wants to make a hundred more. I want to create using a `for` loop. I don't want to enter every single code. How is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a question. How to add a description like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUo7Y.png

Comment: @MahmoudKhoravi description = `content` in my example buddy. Just add any text you want in the return statement in my example. And read the docs, it will tell you.